# Spring Custom Validation With Dynamic Values?

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-form, spring-validator

I have a form that has two fields:

```
    <input id="password"...
    <input id="confirmpassword"...
```

I have a form binding object that binds to these two variables.

```
  class FormBindingClass
   {
       private String password;
       private String confirmPassword;
       ......
       ......
   }
```

Now I validate the above two fields using @NotEmpty and @Pattern validators, however I need to make sure that confirmPassword matches the password ***on the server side!***

If it does not then I need to fail the binding result and show the error back to the user. How can I accomplish this? I explored making custom annotations something like:

```
 @MustMatch(password)
 private String confirmPassword;
```

But I cannot pass dynamic values to annotation can I? How can I solve this tricky issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a validation at your dao layer andfor which ina general case you would throw an exception to the web layer and handle apprppriately.So you have to manually validate this in your business logic and construct the error response at the web layer.

The spring MVC validations are basically for form backed data and which doesn't have any business logic dependency.